# get value from checkbox and show in other activity

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I need get te value from checkbox and show in other activity and  display in textview.

This is the code  FormSupervisar.

```
public class FormSupervisar extends Activity {  
    CheckBox Si;      
    @Override       
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);            
        setContentView(R.layout.formsupervisar);           
        Si=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chBoxSi);  
    }
    public void btnEnviar(View view){
        if (Si.isChecked()){        
            Intent i = new Intent(this,FormBotonSi.class);
            i.putExtra("Si",Si.getText().toString().trim());     
            startActivity(i);  
        }      
    }
```

The activity when i call the string and show the String in a TextView

```
public class FormBotonSi extends Activity {   
    private String ,Si ;     
    private TextView tvTipoInspeccion;                     
    @Override      
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)      
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.formbotonsi);                                           
         Bundle bn1 = getIntent().getExtras();  
         Si = bn1.getString(Si);          
         tvTipoInspeccion.setText(Si.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way.....

```
public class FormBotonSi extends Activity {

......
......

String Si = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Si");  // its "Si" instead of Si


}
```

One more thing... While you code in Java you must follow the Camel case. Field and Methods always starts with small letter whereas Class, Interface, Enums, Constructors starts with Capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Si = bn1.getString("Si");
```

instead of

```
Si = bn1.getString(Si);
```

for getting value in second activity because you are setting "Si" as key in first activity(in FormSupervisar)

OR
You can initialize Si String as:

```
private String Si="Si";    
Si = bn1.getString(Si);
```